# How to access multiple text boxes in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

i am trying fill the text boxes. Each time you get into the page the the number of text boxes will be different and the name of them will be different.

```
<div class="fb-single-line-text">
    <div class="display-flex" data-test-single-line-text-input-wrap="true">
<!---->
      <input name="urn:li:fs_easyApplyFormElement:(urn:li:fs_normalized_jobPosting:2620509178,30257397,numeric)" id="urn:li:fs_easyApplyFormElement:(urn:li:fs_normalized_jobPosting:2620509178,30257397,numeric)" class="ember-text-field ember-view fb-single-line-text__input" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="urn:li:fs_easyApplyFormElement:(urn:li:fs_normalized_jobPosting:2620509178,30257397,numeric)-error-message" data-test-single-line-text-input="" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

the above lines are the html code of first text box

```
<div class="fb-single-line-text">
    <div class="display-flex" data-test-single-line-text-input-wrap="true">
<!---->
      <input name="urn:li:fs_easyApplyFormElement:(urn:li:fs_normalized_jobPosting:2620509178,30257389,numeric)" id="urn:li:fs_easyApplyFormElement:(urn:li:fs_normalized_jobPosting:2620509178,30257389,numeric)" class="ember-text-field ember-view fb-single-line-text__input" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="urn:li:fs_easyApplyFormElement:(urn:li:fs_norm
alized_jobPosting:2620509178,30257389,numeric)-error-message" data-test-single-line-text-input="" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

So i see all of them class name in comman so i tried to get all the e*emphasized text*lemnts inside the class . but i could not find a possible way for it. can someone help me with that

Comment: Try this to locate the `input` tags. `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class,'ember-text-field')]")`

Comment: the code you mentioned helped a lot but if there is a 4 boxes in the pages it return as 5 . like it always come up with 1 extra . i tried to print their name using  text_boxes =self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class,'ember-text-field')]")
                            for text_box in text_boxes:
                                print("the name of the text box is ",text_box.text)        but could not print them

Comment: See what elements that xpath is pointing to in the DOM.

Comment: There must be something unique for those 4 `input` tags. Use that and trace the input tags.

Comment: got it the solution works fine . thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to deal with this situation.

1. use `find_elements` to find out how many input boxes are present in UI, also you could send different message to those input box.

   ```
   total_no_of_input_with_div_single_line_text = len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.fb-single-line-text input"))
   print(total_no_of_input_with_div_single_line_text)
   ```

Now you can `send_keys` to individual elements like this :-

```
total_no_of_input_with_div_single_line_text[0].send_keys('some string')
```

you can always change the index above from `0 to 1, 2 etc.`

second in a loop like this :

```
for ele in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.fb-single-line-text input"):
  ele.send_keys('some value here')
```

2. other way would be to use **xpath indexing** to locate the element.

   ```
   (//div[@class='fb-single-line-text']/descendant::input)[1]
   ```

should locate the first web element input in the page, also you have the access to change that to `[2]`, `[3]` and so on..